# React-select .is-disabled cant change color

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to set color: #aaa when .Select.is-disabled is true, but I cant override the .Select-placeholder style which is color: black;

```
.Select.is-disabled > .Select-control {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: #aaa !important;
}

.Select-placeholder {
  color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: You need to add an working example of the problem with all of the css included. Use codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: Please post the HTML as well as all relevant CSS of the select element.

Comment: You can almost edit every color in the main less file of the resource. There are lots of variables to customize

Comment: Do you want to change placeholder color if select is disabled, or value too, if it exists?

Answer (score 15):

You could use the API that the last version (2) of `react-select` provides, like this way:

```
const customStyles = {
  // For the select it self, not the options of the select
  control: (styles, { isDisabled}) => {
    return {
      ...styles,
      cursor: isDisabled ? 'not-allowed' : 'default',
      // This is an example: backgroundColor: isDisabled ? 'rgba(206, 217, 224, 0.5)' : 'white'
      color: isDisabled ? '#aaa' : 'white'
    }
  },
  // For the options
  option: (styles, { isDisabled}) => {
    const color = chroma(data.color);
    return {
      ...styles,
      backgroundColor: isDisabled ? 'red' : blue,
      color: '#FFF',
      cursor: isDisabled ? 'not-allowed' : 'default',
    };
  },
};
```

Then in the `<Select>` you use these `styles` like this:

```
export default () => (
  <Select
    defaultValue={items[0]}
    label="Single select"
    options={items}
    styles={customStyles}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic CSS knowledge, has nothing to do with `react` or `react-select`..

```
.Select.is-disabled > .Select-control {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: #aaa !important;
}

.Select-placeholder {
  color: black !important;
}
```

CSS reads code up-down, and !important overrides everything that has been read before. now, you have 2 !important, which makes the last one override all former.

To fix this, either remove the !important where color is black, or edit your css like this:

```
.Select.is-disabled > .Select-control {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: #aaa !important;
}

.Select-placeholder {
  color: black !important;
}

.Select.is-disabled {
  color: #aaa !important;
}
```

> But you might see now that you've created a `!important` hell.

### !important should not be used.

It is a quick last resort fix, that causes more trouble than it helps.

try to refactor your css and get rid of all !important statements. important isnt necessary here, just a bit of refactoring to get it work.

Refactor your css with the `UP to DOWN` mindset in your head and I'm sure you are gonna nail it by yourself!